XSLT transformation with lxml produces empty output without errors (Python/AWS)
I'm working on an XML transformation project using Python's lxml library. While reading XML from S3 and parsing works correctly, the transformation produces empty output without any errors.
Issue: XSLT transformation is not throwing any error but output has no data from the raw XML.
Core Code:
class XSLTTransformer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = setup_logger()
        self.transform = None

    def load_xslt(self, paths):
        parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=True)
        parser.resolvers.add(MultiPathResolver())
        
        xsl_path = os.path.join(paths)
        
        with open(xsl_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xsl_file:
            xsl_content = xsl_file.read()
            
        self.transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(bytes(xsl_content, encoding='utf-8')))

    def transform_xml(self, input_xml, paths):
        
        self.load_xslt(paths)
        parser = etree.XMLParser()
        parser.resolvers.add(MultiPathResolver())
        imput_doc = etree.parse(input_xml)
        result = self.transform(imput_doc)
        
        t_xml = etree.tostring(result, pretty_print=True, 
                             xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
                             
        return result

class MultiPathResolver: 
    .....

Sample Input XML:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <id>1</id>
        <org_type>NEW</org_type>
        <org_name>ABC Corp</org_name>
        <org_desc>Sample description</org_desc>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>

XSLT Template:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="idkey" match="ROW" use="org_name"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="ROWSET">
        <OrgInfo>
            <xsl:for-each select="ROW[generate-id()= generate-id(key('idkey', org_name)[1])]">
                <xsl:value-of select="org_type"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="org_name"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </OrgInfo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

What I've verified:
XML is being read correctly from S3
XSLT stylesheet loads successfully
XML elements match the XSLT template names
No errors during transformation
Expected behavior: Transform should output XML with data from input
Actual behavior: Getting valid XML structure but with no data from input
one more question: there is namespace in XSL but not in RAW XML, does the namespace in xsl can cause problem?

I ran your XSLT using your XML input in xsltproc and received <?xml version="1.0"?> <OrgInfo>NEWABC Corp</OrgInfo> as the result.

What result do you expect? Maybe you can add the expected xml in the question, too.

Due to Data privacy issue, I didn't add the actual XML data and XSL data , above is the example how it would look like.

Please edit your question and add the exact result you get with the posted code, along with the result you expect to get.

Please don't tell us your desired result but show us. All XSLT parses input to generate output. [Edit] your post to show us your desired output with the XML input and XSLT you do show.
